# Android Google Play navigation drawer style

Tags: java, android, android-listview, navigation-drawer

There is any tutorial or code how to make the navigation drawer listview will be show like
Google Play or Google Play Music Navigation Drawer?

I want my Nav Drawer look like this: 
[image]

Can you help me with this?

Thanks

Haim.

EDIT:I know how to build navigation drawer, I want a style for the navigation drawer that my nav drawer will look like the google play navigation drawer(big listview tabs....).
If you can write the code.

EDIT2:I used this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WeQzZUroAs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use navigation drawer like facebook on one or both side,try this :

[Android - Is Navigation Drawer from right hand side possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156340/android-is-navigation-drawer-from-right-hand-side-possible/23286965#23286965)

Answer (score 1):

Easy implementation can be achieve with google buildin 
 navigation drawer

[Link](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SlidingMenu library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu).

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="5"
android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Works for APi-5+ and is widely used.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **my posts**. Maybe you will get an idea on how to achieve that.

Here are the links:

[Unable to use AndroidDrawer (sidebar like facebook)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22431553/unable-to-use-androiddrawer-sidebar-like-facebook/22431651#22431651)

From here you can navigate to my different posts.

Hope this helps.. :)